# Yii2- Form: I want to create 3 separate text field but with same name for Phone Number something like this (xxx - xxx-xxxx)

Tags: forms, yii2-advanced-app

I would like to create a phone number field in Yii2 form with 3 separate text fields but with same name: 
[something like image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLLUz.png)
Not sure how that works in Yii2

Answer (score 0):

You should add public functions BeforeSave and AfterFind in you Model like this

```
//this method do some operations before your data will be insert in table
public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

            // now $this->phone is array, but we can't care array in mysql table, so we must encode it to string
            if (is_array($this->phone))
                     $this->phone = implode('-',$this->phone);


            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

// this method do some operations after ActiveForm get information from DB
    public function afterFind() {
        $this->phone = explode('-',$this->phone);
        // revert operation, now $this->phone is array
    }
```

Then you should change phone inputs name in your activeform view, they should be recorded as array in $_POST

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'phone[]')->textInput() ?> <?= $form->field($model, 'phone[]')->textInput() ?> <?= $form->field($model, 'phone[]')->textInput() ?>
```

Because of `[]` after phone, its name will be like this `modelName[phone][]`, and `phone` will be recorded in $_POST as array, then before putting it in DB it will be converted in string.

**DO NOT FORGET:** you should also change rules for this field